# Seeking Insight on an Infinite Series Involving Double Factorials

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm delving into an interesting infinite series and looking for insights or validation on a specific part of it. The series is as follows:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!!}$$
This series can be broken down into the sum of even and odd double factorials:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)!!} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)!!}$$
While the even part simplifies to $\sqrt{e}$, the odd part is more challenging. I've derived an expression for the odd part, which seems to be equivalent to a more complex expression involving Fresnel integrals and other advanced mathematical concepts. However, I'm having trouble confirming this equivalence.

I'm particularly interested in understanding why the odd double factorial part is equivalent to the following expression:
$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N} }^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n}{n!} \times \left[ \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N} }^{\infty} \frac{2^{-2n}}{(4n+1)\times(2n)!} - \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N} }^{\infty} \frac{2^{-(2n+1)}}{(4n+3)\times(2n+1)!} \right]$$
Any insights or suggestions on proving this equivalence would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

[image]

Comment: have you tried expressing the double factorial  with the factorial?

Comment: Yeah，It's relatively easy to express a double factorial using a regular factorial for even numbers, but it becomes more complicated for odd numbers.